# Rippled Installation

Tags: open-source, software-distribution

I am willing to install rippled on my Linux 3.13.0. following : Installation on Ubuntu with alien

https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#installation-on-centosred-hat-with-yum

But I am stuck at this line :

sudo systemctl enable rippled.service

Furthermore, I followed all the anteriors steps but it seems my terminal doesn't recognized the service

->rippled : unrecognized service
->rippled.service : unrecognized service

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you tried to install the latest version 0.32... 
Try to navigate to /opt/ripple/bin and see if the rippled executable is there

Comment: if so try to start rippled manually from there using ./rippled

Comment: I tried but I don"t have the pemission to run the rippled exec.

Comment: Linux says  can not change permissions for this file since I am not the owner.

Comment: The owner of that executable is the user 'rippled' try to start the ./rippled with sudo

Comment: ./rippled => permission not granted || sudo ./ rippled => command not found  || sudo rippled => command not found

Comment: try 'cd /opt/ripple/bin' ; then 'ls' and see if the rippled executable is in this directory if not the installation hasnt cmpleted successfully

Comment: I can see the ripple file, it is for sure in the repository

Comment: It was a right problem. "sudo" didn't fix anything but "sudo chmod 777 rippled" works, thanks for your help

Comment: Thats the same problem I had. I believe this happens when you start the rippled exe as root, because then the owner of all the db directories is root. Your description was a little condusing, although. So I wanted you to be sure your installation completed sucessfully. I will link a page in the ripple forum maybe you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem just a few days ago. I found an answer by posting this problem in the xrpchat forum. This is the thread: 
http://www.xrpchat.com/topic/1761-cant-run-rippled-as-service/

To sum it up you should do the following steps :

1. Check the installation completed sucessfully, by navigating in the rippled installation directory. In order to do so run these commands.
   `cd /opt/ripple/bin` and then `ls`. Now see if there is the "rippled" executable.
2. Next try to run the rippled service by running `sudo systemctl start rippled.service`
3. Check the latest output of the rippled service by running `sudo systemctl status rippled.service`. If it runs - congratulations you're done. If it doesnt there might be a variety of problems. In this particular case: If the output contains something like "permission denied", do step 4.
4. Check all directories mentioned in the output you got from the previous step. To do so navigate to the parent directory of the desired path with `cd` and there run `ls -la`. The owner of all these directories must be a user called "rippled"
5. If the owner is root run `sudo chown -R rippled:rippled /path/to/dir`
6. Try to run the service again as explained in step 2

Beside the mentioned forum other helpful links might be the official ripple forum:https://forum.ripple.com/

And the official installation instructions: 
https://ripple.com/build/rippled-setup/#installation-on-ubuntu-with-alien